# In chainer, How to write BPTT updater using multiple GPUs?

Tags: chainer

I don't find example because existing example only extends training.StandardUpdater, thus only use One GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the `BPTTUpdater` of [the ptb example of Chainer](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/ptb/train_ptb.py).

It's not straight forward to make the customized updater support learning on multiple GPUs. The `MultiprocessParallelUpdater` hard code the way to compute the gradient (only the target link implementation is customizable), so you have to copy the overall implementation of `MultiprocessParallelUpdater` and modify the gradient computation parts. What you have to copy and edit is [`chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py`](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/training/updaters/multiprocess_parallel_updater.py).

There are two parts in this file that compute gradient; one in `_Worker.run`, which represents a worker process task, and the other in `MultiprocessParallelUpdater.update_core`, which represents the master process task. You have to make these code do BPTT by modifying the code starting from `_calc_loss` to `backward` in each of these two parts:

```
# Change self._master into self.model for _Worker.run code
loss = _calc_loss(self._master, batch)
self._master.cleargrads()
loss.backward()
```

It should be modified by inserting the code of `BPTTUpdater.update_core`.

You also have to take care on the data iterators. `MultiprocessParallelUpdater` accept the set of iterators that will be distributed to master/worker processes. Since the ptb example uses a customized iterator (`ParallelSequentialIterator`), you have to make sure that these iterators iterate over different portions of the dataset or using different initial offsets of word positions. It may require customization to `ParalellSequentialIterator` as well.

Comment: sounds complicated, hope there is example.